# Keeping track of an HTML5 variable in SCORM

Tags: javascript, html, scorm

I've recently been making a small HTML5 project to be integrated into a E-Learning package.  Essentially it's like a small HTML5 game that the user must complete successfully in order to pass the course.  However I have no knowledge of SCORM or e-learning packages.  I pressumed it would be easy to keep a track of if a person had succesfully completed the game as a variable inside the html5 and use it to pass onto the next part of the course to say if they'd passed or not.  However when I handed over my section to the company that were integrating it into the course they were unsure how it could link in.

Is there an easy way to move a (pass/fail) variable between SCORM pages... or maybe choose what part of the course to do next based on a variable in HTML5?
Alternatively is there an easy way to read or write to a external file that could be stored in an e-learning environment?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCORM provides a mechanism called "objectives" to track pass/fail (or complete/incomplete) and a score.

The data model elements you'd need to set to do so would be:

> cmi.objectives.n.id (CMIIdentifier, RW) Unique label for the objective
>
> cmi.objectives.n.status ("passed", "completed", "failed", "incomplete", "browsed", "not attempted", RW) Indicates whether the learner has completed or satisfied the objective

So, assuming you have a reference to the SCORM API called `API` and no other objectives have been set, you could do something like:

```
API.LMSSetValue("cmi.objectives.0.id", "IDForYourObjective");
API.LMSSetValue("cmi.objectives.0.status", "passed");
```

And the pass/fail value could later be checked with:

```
objectiveStatus = API.LMSGetValue("cmi.objectives.0.status");
```

If there potentially are other objectives, you'll need to check the count ( `cmi.objectives._count` ) and use that to determine the next available index (rather than `0` above).

If you were the only one who would need to read and write data, you could consider using `cmi.suspend_data` (which is just an unstructured bucket). It's not my first suggestion because you mentioned your work would be integrated with someone else's, so I'd avoid using that without verifying they aren't going to also use it.

More SCORM runtime information: https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/

How to find the SCORM API: https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/api-discovery-algorithms/

In this response, I'm assuming that this is to be included in a SCORM 1.2 single-SCO package. The response would be similar, but slightly different for 2004 (as you can see in the link above). If this is multi-SCO content, whoever is packaging your work together into a content package would have to declare the objective you're creating as a "global objective" so that other SCOs could read its value.

Answer (score 0):

### Pages:

If you have individual HTML pages that initialize this would require you to possibly wrap all that up in a IFRAME.  Main reason is a LMS could be listening to your load/unload between pages and since each page would have to insatiate a connection back to the SCORM API it may "think" the SCO unloaded.  There is a possibility it wouldn't but I'd still side on caution.  Of course you can do individual pages too.

### Communication

SCORM is a JavaScript communication model.  I talk at length about it on GitHub here https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/wiki. This will expand on all the areas discussed and provide some examples.

### Versions

Typically if your after the bare minimum you can determine if you're using SCORM 1.2 or 2004.  Then determine if you want to set the score and status appropriately to match.

### Status

Completion = Progress essentially.  Did the student see enough.
Success = Pass/fail - did they score high enough.

Good Luck.